# How do I solve a certain differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I need to find out a solution to the equation:

```
z r[z] r''[z] - (d - 1) r[z] (r'[z])^3 - (d-2) z (r'[z])^2 - 
  (d - 1) r[z] r'[z] - (d - 2) z == 0
```

subject to the boundary conditions: `r[0] == R` and `r'[z0] = ∞`.

It's known that a solution exists and it is: `r^2 + z^2 == R^2`, I tried:

```
DSolve[
  {z r[z] r''[z] - (d - 1) r[z] (r'[z])^3 - (d - 2) z (r'[z])^2 - 
    (d - 1) r[z] r'[z] - (d - 2) z == 0, 
   r[0] == R, r'[z0] == ∞}, 
  r[z], z]
```

The equation and the solution can be found in arXiv: [hep-th/0605073](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0605073.pdf) page 43, eqn. 7.8

Comment: You already have the answer:`r^2 + z^2 = R^2`, so what's the problem.?

Comment: what is `zr[z]` ? Is this supposed to be `z*r[z]` and what is `r'[SubStar[z]] ==` is supposed to be? if `SubStar[z]` is supposed to be some constant, why not write `r'[z0]` or such so it is clear?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I have the solution but don't know how to solve the equation.

Comment: @Nasser Yes zr[z] means z*r[z] and SubStar[z] is supposed to be a constant, sorry for the obscurity, I shall modify the question.

Comment: You believe the solution is independent of `d`? Why?

Comment: It seems that `z0` (or `SubStar[z]` should be equal to `R` (or possibly `-R`), yes?

Comment: Re: "I have the solution but don't know how to solve the equation." `DSolve` will not show you how to solve the equation. It will only give you the solution, or fail to.  One might get a hint from the general solution it provided: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mFPVz.jpg

Comment: @MichaelE2. Not guilty. Someone else made that edit.

Comment: @Michael E2 Yes z0 is equal to R.

Comment: @m_goldberg Both the equation and its solution are provided in a paper, although I don't know exactly why it's independent of d but d indicates the no. of spatial dimensions; the solution to the equation will define a surface in d dimensional space and that surface is expected not to change with d.

Comment: Even the result of d = 3; DSolve[
 z*r[z]*r''[z] - (d - 1)*r[z]*(r'[z])^3 - (d - 2)*
    z*(r'[z])^2 - (d - 1)*r[z]*r'[z] - (d - 2)*z == 0, r[z], z] is complex.

Answer (score 3):

```
d = 2; sol = 
 DSolve[{z r[z] r''[z] - (d - 1) r[
       z] (r'[z])^3 - (d - 2) z (r'[z])^2 - (d - 1) r[z] r'[
       z] - (d - 2) z == 0}, r[z], z]

(*Out[]= {{r[z] -> 
   0}, {r[z] -> -I E^-C[1] Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 C[1]) z^2] + C[2]}, {r[z] ->
    I E^-C[1] Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 C[1]) z^2] + C[2]}}*)
 s = r[z] /. sol[[3]] /. C[2] -> 0

(*Out[]= I E^-C[1] Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 C[1]) z^2]*)
Solve[s^2 + z^2 == R^2, C[1]]

(*Out[]= {{C[1] -> 
   ConditionalExpression[1/2 (2 I \[Pi] C[2] + Log[1/R^2]), 
    C[2] \[Element] Integers]}}*)
```

Consequently $r(z)=\pm \sqrt {R^2-z^2}$

Note that in the article [Aspects of Holographic Entanglement Entropy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0605073.pdf) the authors cited another equation on p.34
$$ rzz′′ + (d−1)z(z′)^3 + (d−1)zz′ + dr(z′)^2 + dr = 0.
$$
For this equation, the solution $z^2+r^2=R^2$ exists for any $d$.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$\rho^2 = z^2+r^2\quad\text{and}\quad \left({ds\over dz}\right)^2 = 1 + \left({dr \over dz}\right)^2\,.$$ 
Then the ODE is equivalent to
$$z\,{d^2(\rho^2) \over dz^2}
 = (d-1)\left({ds\over dz}\right)^2 {d(\rho^2) \over dz} \,.$$
By inspection $\rho^2 = \text{constant}$ is a solution.

Check (there's a factor of two difference between the equations):

```
ode = z r[z] r''[z] -
 (d - 1) r[z] (r'[z])^3 - (d - 2) z (r'[z])^2 - (d - 1) r[z] r'[z] -
 (d - 2) z;
With[{ds = Sqrt[1 + r'[z]^2], ρ = Sqrt[z^2 + r[z]^2]},
 2 ode - (z D[ρ^2, {z, 2}] - (d - 1) ds^2 D[ρ^2, z]) // 
  Simplify
 ]
(*  0  *)
```